# React Component's render method called twice even after data fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, immutable.js

**`ListFolders`** is a React component. And "**folders**" data prop passed to this component from **`MainLayout`** component.

**`MainLayout`** component uses redux `connect` and gets "**folders**".

Here, my problem inside **`ListFolders`**, there are some mapping and calculations while listing folders. So because second call it takes more time and this is an important performance issue.

Basic example below. I am using `redux-saga` and `immutable.js`. 
I am getting `name (ContainerDesc)`, `id (IdEncrypted)`, `haveChildFolders` and `childFolders`.

> Here, it enters inside `if (folders !== undefined) { ...` code block twice.

```
render() {
    const { classes, folders } = this.props;

    let reactListItems = [];
    if (folders !== undefined) {

        var iterator1 = folders[Symbol.iterator]();

        for (let item of iterator1) {

            reactListItems.push({ 
                'name': item.get('ContainerDesc'), 
                'id': item.get('IdEncrypted'),
                'haveChildFolders' : item.get('ChildContainers').size > 0,
                'childFolders': item.get('ChildContainers')
            })

        }
    }

    return (
        <List classes={{ root: classes.list, }}>
            ...
        </List>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For second call, folders data might haven't changed and may not be undefined so add one more condition that checks folders data had changed or not in componentWillReceiveProps() something like :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){    
     if (folders.length !== nextProps.folders.length) {
       return ...
    }
}
```

Or you can add condition shouldComponentUpdate() and stop component to get updated if condition is not satisfied

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){    
         if (folders.length !== nextProps.folders.length) {
           return true
        }
        else{
          return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used shouldComponentUpdate and discovered a new thing. After folders already taken and written to *this.props.folder*, it re-enters render method with this.props.folders is undefined again.

Comment: check value of nextProps.folders, it might include required folders data  so store it in the state or any variable and use it in the render method

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for `ListFolders` called twice. 
I am using `ListFolders` inside `SidebarComponent` and in `Sidebar` i used material-ui `hidden` helper for desktop and mobile menus. Example code below.

```
<Hidden mdUp implementation="css">
   ...
   <Drawer variant="temporary" ... /* Sidebar Drawer */
</Hidden>

<Hidden smDown implementation="css">
   ...
   <Drawer variant="temporary" ... /* Sidebar Drawer */
</Hidden>
```

Because of that `ListFolders` renders multiple times even data fetched.
I will handle mobile menu with pure css i think.